# Data structure for storing unique values

Tags: c++, c

I need to keep data of the following form:

```
(a,b,1),
(c,d,2),
(e,f,3),
(g,h,4),
(i,j,5),
(k,l,6),
(m,a,7)
...
```

such that the integers within the data (3rd column) are consecutively ordered and are unique. Also there are 2,954,208,208 such rows. I am searching for a data structure which returns the value of the 3rd column given the value of first two columns e.g.

```
   Given: (i,j) it returns 5
```

And given the value of 3rd column, first two columns can be retrieved. For example,

```
   Given: 5 it returns (a,b)
```

Is there some data structure which may help me achieve the same.

My approach towards solving this problem was to use hash-maps..but hash-maps do not turn out to be efficient. Is there some other way out.

The values in the first, second and third column are all of 64-bit.

I have 4GB of RAM.

Comment: I think its called a database

Comment: 3 billion rows is a *lot*. How much RAM do you have? At that scale, you might be best off using a relational database.

Comment: 4GB of Ram will require A LOT of time to process 3 billion rows

Comment: That is a massive amount of data. Use sqlite and store this information in a database. Create an index on the first 2 columns and the 3rd column. Your primary key should probably be the 3rd column

Comment: To do efficient lookups in both directions, you'll actually need two data structures. The requirement that column 3 is unique and consecutively ordered lends itself well to using an array or database table with integer identity primary key. This will give constant time lookups when retrieving columns 1 and 2 given column 3. For efficient lookups in the reverse direction, you'll need a secondary index (either implemented by the database, or using something like a hash map or more likely a binary search tree).

Comment: some ppl suggested using a database. if your main priority is to have a quick implementation, use one. if you need high performance (= using the data structure is a bottleneck), don't. perhaps you should update your question....

Comment: Depending on your use case, there may be other options. If you just need to display the value to the user given a key, a database is probably your best option--4GB is not enough to hold all of your rows in memory. You might check out SQLite or BerkeleyDB, they both have clean c/c++ interfaces and can be embedded right in your program. If you're doing something more like one time analysis on the rows, you might be able to find a way to process them in smaller batches or a streaming/online approach. Without knowing the meaning of the data and what your goals are, it's not really possible to say.